# Covering Letter for Europe stay

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, accommodation, czech-republic, invitation-letters

I am travelling to Europe for two months and I have a covering letter from my uncle from Czech Republic which states that he will bear all my expenses and accommodation during the two month stay. My itinerary includes my stay at my uncle's place to see him and also other few countries like Germany, Italy and Switzerland for leisure.

Now the question is: do I need to show my bank balance also for it and if yes how much should it be? And secondly, if I don't have sufficient bank balance, will I not be given Schengen visa although I have a strong covering letter?

I am an Indian Citizen, I will be applying the visa in Czech Embassy as my relatives belong there and also my no. of days are maximum in Czech only.

Comment: Welcome! Which visa are you applying for? What citizenship do you have? The more detail you can include, and the clearer you can make your question (please edit it, don't answer this in comments), the more likely someone here can help you. It's quite hard to read at the moment...

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/bank-balance-for-getting-a-schengen-visa and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44577/schengen-visa-for-germany-refused-due-to-lack-of-subsistence

Comment: @raman Did you not need a "hosting document" of some sort from your uncle, attested by the town-hall?

Comment: Did you not need a "hosting document" of some sort from your uncle, attested by the town-hall?
I did not get your question

Comment: @drN Not all European countries ask for that. Netherlands I know of. Swiss don't ask for it.

Comment: @DumbCoder Ok. So Netherlands and the Swiss don't as for it. That's interesting and useful for people applying for tourist visas.

Comment: @drN - Sorry my sentence was constructed in a wrong manner. Netherlands ask but Swiss don't.

Comment: What @drN meant is that some countries/consulates need more than a simple invitation letter, they want a specific document that your uncle would have to request from the authorities of the town where he lives. It could be different in the Czech Republic but you should not assume that a letter from your uncle is enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you to convince the consulate that you do fulfill all the requirements and if bank statements are missing they are going to suspect you are trying to hide something, which does not help your application.

As far as the “means of subsistence” requirement is concerned, you need a specific amount of cash per day plus enough money to pay for the flight. But if your uncle is ready to cover the accommodation costs and the flight tickets, you would theoretically not need to have much money on your bank account.

For your uncle support to count in a Schengen visa application, you would usually need more than a letter, namely some sort of “certificate” issued by the police or the town where your host lives and some proof of his income/financial means (e.g. his bank statements). I do not read Czech and have no experience with visas for this particular country, but some info I found does suggest it's the same in the Czech Republic (see e.g. [policie.cz](http://www.policie.cz/clanek/informace-pro-pobyt-cizincu-pozvani-k-navsteve-cr.aspx) and [mzv.cz](http://www.mzv.cz/jnp/cz/informace_pro_cizince/kratkodobe_vizum/vizum_k_pobytu_do_90_dnu_za_ucelem_3.html)).

The problem is that bank statements can also go a long way towards fulfilling another requirement, namely providing assurances that you will return to your country of residence at the end of the visa. Here the point is not whether you have a lot of money on the account right now but whether you get a regular income. That's why consulates usually require three months worth of bank statements and not merely your last statement.

If you have some other way to establish your ties to your country of origin (a spouse staying behind, a house you own, maybe even simply a university registration) *and* you submit a proper certificate + proof of funds from your uncle, you might be able to get a visa without providing your own bank statements but it would in any case weaken your application. And if you have no way to show tangible ties to your place of residence (e.g. you are young with no family of your own, have a cash-only job and no property), getting a visa could be incredibly difficult, even with an invitation.

Comment: There are English versions of the pages you linked to: http://www.policie.cz/docDetail.aspx?docid=21563997&doctype=ART and http://www.mzv.cz/jnp/en/information_for_aliens/short_stay_visa/visa_for_a_stay_up_to_90_days_for_the_3.html.